# Accessing enum in data access layer

Tags: c#, enums, data-access-layer

Is there any way to use/access an enum contained in a data access layer project without referencing the actual project (in order to try and keep certain things separate)?

For example I have one project say `UI` that references a project say `MIDDLEMAN` and another project say `DAL`. If my `UI` has a reference to `MIDDLEMAN` who in turn has a reference to `DAL` where the enum is contained, can I access the enum from `UI`?

Comment: Please give more details. If you need to specify the actual enum in your DAL, how do you expect that to work without a reference to the declaring project?

Comment: you may create separate "interface" project that contains only shared parts..

Comment: @jonSkeet have edited

Comment: @rudolf_franek has a good solution: obviously DAL should only expose it's classes to MIDDLEMAN via interfaces, so move those and the enum  to COMMON and allow all three to access that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two options:

The first is to create a separate project that both the other layers can access and use the enum from. If you do this, make sure to keep that project as simple as possible. What I mean is be careful not to add logic there that is related directly to either of the other projects, and that will create unwanted dependencies.

Your other option is to create a similar enum in your `MiddleMan` layer, and map from the enum in the `DAL` layer to this new enum. Since your UI can reference the `MiddleMan`, it should be able to use this new enum, while still keeping the lower level enum out of reach. Any changes to the lower level enum will then have to be adjusted for in the mapping logic.

Comment: I suppose I was wondering if you could persist the actual enum through the middle project somehow but it sounds like that's not possible

Answer (score 4):

If I work on n-tier layer program, I usually create a project name "DataTypes" which store any share data through any other layer project.

So I can include enum or 'data class' to the project that need to use them without duplicate them or add ref from one project layer to another.

Answer (score 0):

you could move the enum in a seperate project and add this to both projects you did not want to combine :)

Comment: I'd like the enum to be contained in the DAL project really

Comment: maybe you can use this answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065526/how-to-get-an-enum-value-from-an-assembly-using-late-binding-in-c-sharp