# Unable to retrieve enum type if the definition is located inside a class via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, enums

How to retrieve the enum type if the enum is defined within a class?

Adapted from the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3068563/3834):

```
namespace GetEnumReflectionTesting
{
    enum Foo { Bar = 5 }
    public class MyClass
    {
        enum Foo { Bar =6}
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Get the assembly containing the enum - Here it's the one executing
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();


            var enumType = assembly.GetType("GetEnumReflectionTesting.Foo"); //this obtains the GetEnumReflectionTesting.Foo
            var enumBarValue = enumType.GetField("Bar").GetValue(null);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", enumBarValue, (int)enumBarValue);

            var enumType2 = assembly.GetType("GetEnumReflectionTesting.MyClass.Foo"); //but instead of GetEnumReflectionTesting.MyClass.Foo, this returns a null!
            var enumBarValue2 = enumType2.GetField("Bar").GetValue(null);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", enumBarValue2, (int)enumBarValue2);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's something interesting, `enumType` retrieves the `GetEnumReflectionTesting.Foo` as expected, but `enumType2` instead of retrieve `GetEnumReflectionTesting.MyClass.Foo`, it returns a `null`!

So what is the robust way to retrieve the enum type regardless of whether it is defined within a class, or not?

Note that in my scenario, the `Foo` enum is defined within a class, and I get it from third party vendor which I can't change. So don't suggest me moving the `Foo` enum outside of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+` to separate a top-level class name from the nested class name:

```cs
var enumType2 = assembly.GetType("GetEnumReflectionTesting.MyClass+Foo");
// ...............................................................^

var enumBarValue2 = enumType2.GetField("Bar").GetValue(null);
Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", enumBarValue2, (int)enumBarValue2);
```

That much will result in:

```
Bar|6
```

---

Another way to do it is to get the top-level type and then call `GetNestedType` on it.

```cs
var containingType2 = assembly.GetType("GetEnumReflectionTesting.MyClass");
var enumType2 = containingType2.GetNestedType("Foo", BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var enumBarValue3 = enumType2.GetField("Bar").GetValue(null);
Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", enumBarValue3, (int)enumBarValue3);
```

*Note that you have to use `Bindingflags.NonPublic` because the way you've defined the nested `Foo` enum is implicitly private.  If the library you're using has the nested type as `public`, you can omit that parameter.*